# How to override collectionView in a UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am wondering whether it's possible to programatically override the `collectionView` with your own UICollectionView subclass for a UICollectionViewController.

On a regular UIViewController I would do this:

```
public override func loadView() {
    view = UIViewSubclass()
}
```

And while this works for the `view` property, the `collectionView` references nil.

How would one properly override it when building a custom UICollectionViewController and UICollectionView completelly programatically?

Comment: Why not to take a regular `UIViewController` and attach a `UICOllectionViewV to it?

Comment: @MaxPevsner that's my plan B. And I'll probably go ahead with it if there's nothing better.

Answer (score 2):

i think when the `UICollectionViewColtroller` override the `loadView` function, it's not only set the value of `view`, also `collectionView`. And in `UICollectionViewController` `view` and `collectionView` is not the same view

So i think you should add the code to set the value of `collectionView`